# Can code be executed from copying the From field of an Outlook Email?

Tags: email, macos, outlook

I received a suspicious email in Outlook and wanted to check the from email field to see if it was still a Microsoft address.

1. I right clicked and selected "copy address" on the From field of an email in Outlook.
2. I attempted to paste from clipboard into Notes, a MacBook default text editor.
3. Outlook closed itself, and then reopened on its on over about 10 seconds.
4. A warning popped up, to which I replied Deny immediately without fully reading.

I tried to find the warning message online based on what I remember seeing, and this looks like it. Note, this is only an example that looks similar to the one I saw.

[image: Example Image]

In hindsight, touching a suspicious email at all is bad, but I had always assumed copying the sender's email into notepad was safe. How wrong am I, and was denying it access and restarting Outlook enough to assuage the danger?

Comment: welcome @daniel - if possible, can you please edit this post to make it clearer the sequence of events that occurred, and that the screenshot is only an example of the decision you *might* have been presented with? (ps. i can't see how copying information from outlook to notepad would cause outlook to close - what is "notes"?)

Comment: This sounds more like a glitch in Outlook than anything malicious

Comment: Brynk, Thanks, I have updated as best I could to be clearer, and reiterated that the example is not the actual example.

@schroeder   I honestly had not considered that it could be just an error. The combination of a very suspicious email, the unexpected behavior, and the security warning immediately made me jump to assuming malicious intent. I'm not overly familiar with MacBooks and Outlook on them, but I thought they were supposed to be fairly stable.